# How to convert $\frac{1}{2\pi}\int_{0}^{2\pi}\sqrt{(ucos(\theta)+v\sin(\theta))^2-(u^2+v^2-1)} d\theta$ to an elliptic integral?

Tags: calculus, integration, elliptic-functions

How do we solve

$$\frac{1}{2\pi}\int_{0}^{2\pi}\sqrt{(ucos(\theta)+v\sin(\theta))^2-(u^2+v^2-1)} d\theta$$

According to Mathematica the answer is

$$\frac{1}{2\pi}E(u^2+v^2) \implies u^2+v^2\le1$$

Where $E(x)$ is the Complete Elliptic integral of the second kind.

$$E(x)=\int_{0}^{\pi/2}\sqrt{1+k^2\sin^2(\theta)}d\theta$$

How do I convert the integral into an elliptic integral?

My attempt is below

$$\frac{1}{2\pi}\int_{0}^{2\pi}\sqrt{u^2cos^2(\theta)+2uv\sin(\theta)\cos(\theta)+v^2\sin(\theta)^2-(u^2+v^2-1)} d\theta$$

$$\frac{1}{2\pi}\int_{0}^{2\pi}\sqrt{u^2-u^2\sin^2(\theta)+2uv\sin(\theta)\cos(\theta)+v^2\sin(\theta)^2-(u^2+v^2-1)} d\theta$$

$$\frac{1}{2\pi}\int_{0}^{2\pi}\sqrt{u^2+2uv\sin(\theta)\cos(\theta)+(v^2-u^2)\sin(\theta)^2-(u^2+v^2-1)} d\theta$$

I'm not sure how to continue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider:

$$\int_{0}^{2\pi}\sqrt{(u \cos(\theta)+v\sin(\theta))^2-(u^2+v^2-1)} ~d \theta$$

Now introduce new parameters:

$$u=r \sin \phi \\ v=r \cos \phi$$

$$u^2+v^2=r^2$$

You get:

$$\int_{0}^{2\pi}\sqrt{r^2 \sin^2 (\theta + \phi)-r^2+1}~d \theta = $$

$$\sqrt{1-r^2} \int_{0}^{2\pi}\sqrt{1+k^2 \sin^2 (\theta + \phi)}~d \theta \color{blue}{=} $$

Where:

$$k^2=\frac{r^2}{1-r^2}$$

Move to the new variable:

$$x=\theta+\phi$$

$$\color{blue}{=} \sqrt{1-r^2} \int_{\phi}^{2\pi+\phi}\sqrt{1+k^2 \sin^2 x}~d x$$

This is of course, an incomplete elliptic integral of the second kind. However, experiments with different $\phi$ indicate that the value is represented in terms of complete elliptic integral and doesn't depend on $\phi$.

I'm sure there's a way to prove it.

Comment: So the integral in terms of the incomplete integral of the second kind is $\sqrt{1-u^2-v^2}E(2\pi,\sqrt{\frac{u^2+v^2}{1-u^2-v^2}})$

Comment: It seems so, but I can't be sure, I don't have access to Mathematica to check extensively. The limits give me pause